Gradle build failing to get dependency from Bitbucket maven repository from branches other than master
So, I have created a custom maven repo on BitBucket.
These are the steps I followed:
First I created the aar of library
./gradlew :designsystem:assemble

Then I published to local repo
afterEvaluate {
publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("SADS") {
        groupId = "com.strollby.libraries"
        artifactId = "design-system"
        version = "1.0.2"
        pom.packaging = "aar"
        artifact(file("../designsystem/build/outputs/aar/designsystem-release.aar"))

        pom.withXml {
            val dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
            configurations.getByName("implementation") {
                dependencies.forEach {
                    val dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "RemoteDispatch"
            url = uri("..")
        }
    }
}
}

Publish:
./gradlew publishSADSPublicationToRemoteDispatchRepository

Then I pushed to remote branch master.
And to access the artifact:
   maven {
        credentials {
            username = "nitheesh"
            password = "xxxxx"
        }
        authentication {
            create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
        }
        url =
            uri("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/strollby/android-design-system/src/master")
    }

And
 implementation("com.strollby.libraries:design-system:1.0.0")

From master branch everything works fine as I expected.
But, I have a different branch named releases. If I use that, I.e, https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/strollby/android-design-system/src/releases only latest version works. Both branch have same exact content.
implementation("com.strollby.libraries:design-system:1.0.2") - works
implementation("com.strollby.libraries:design-system:1.0.0") - not work

I get an error Failed to resolve: Strollby Design System:designsystem:unspecified.
This is the maven-metadata.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <metadata>
 <groupId>com.strollby.libraries</groupId>
   <artifactId>design-system</artifactId>
   <versioning>
   <latest>1.0.2</latest>
   <release>1.0.2</release>
   <versions>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20240425063043</lastUpdated>

Also, I tried with a different repo. In that even master branch won't work.
Where am I doing wrong? This thing is bugging me a lot.

Try this https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/

wagongit won't work with gradle 7+

It's issue with transitive dependencies.
  implementation("com.strollby.libraries:design-system:1.0.3"){
    isTransitive = false
   }

Solved the issue!
